# GNU Radio: Set or get the phase from carrier of UHD USRP Sink block

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, software-defined-radio, uhd

I am trying to transmit a signal with a carrier of 2.4GHz and then switch to 2.5GHz. It is important for my project to know the phase difference between the received 2.4GHz and the 2.5GHz signals but, since the starting phase when the switch is done seems to be random, I cannot do that. Anyone knows if I can set the starting phase to Zero or ask for this starting phase?

I've read the documentation and some posts and I cannot find any useful information about this.

Comment: Hey  @Jonas, thanks for all the tag maintenance work! Much appreciated!